# How does Linux handle drivers when changing systems?

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, hardware

This has always made me wonder but how does Linux handle device drivers from system to system, so say you plug it in on computer A and then move to computer B with completely different specs.
In addition would the drivers also be affected if you had a persistant install and moved it to another PC, would the kernel just adjust its self at boot, of course this question is outside of custom compiled kernels.

Comment: in short: unless you have **very** unusual hardware, the only problems you're likely to encounter when moving a linux system from one machine to another (or to/from a VM) is 1. `/etc/fstab` probably needs to be edited to match the new disk/partition/filesystem layout (if it's a clone and not just moving the disk from the original machine to a new machine), 2. grub will probably need to be re-installed / updated for the same reason, and 3. the network device(s) get renamed because the MAC address(es) have changed.  Everything else will be auto-detected and just work.

Answer (score 2):

Linux drivers are kernel modules.

This means they can be part of the big binary file that is the kernel (and therefore built-in), or loaded later after the kernel starts.

The only drivers you really have to have built into the kernel are those to access the root filesystem.  Even then, it's possible to have a useable system without such drivers if you have everything you need on an initial RAM disk.  (The bootloader is responsible for loading both the kernel binary and initial RAM disk, and then the bootloader tells the kernel where the initial RAM disk is when it launches the kernel.)

So there's a couple of things that can happen and it's entirely up to you:

- You can build a kernel with all the drivers it needs built-in.  You would then create appropriate files in `/dev` with `mknod` or similar and they would just work.  This is the way UNIX and early Linux worked.  Of course if you run the kernel + initial RAM disk on a different system some of the devices will not work, and if your hard disk controller was one of them you won't be able to boot successfully.
- You can have a userspace process load drivers.  One job of kernel initialization is to ready the `proc` and `sys` virtual filesystems which give access to ACPI and PCI busses, which can be further scanned to determine present hardware.  The responsible executables and support files can be on the initial RAM disk.  This is pretty much what `udev` and `systemd` are.  On a traditional Linux init system, `udev` will be one of the first services spawned in the background and it will go through ACPI and all busses and dynamically create `/dev` nodes.  On a newer `systemd` based system, the functionality of `udev` is included within it and it will do the same.

The second case is typically how many Linux kernels + userland tools are installed.  Linux pretty much starts over at each boot and doesn't reference anything in a registry-like system like Windows does.

I will be honest and the above is probably missing some details because I don't know them myself but that is the basic gist of it.  Something I have read is that the kernel itself can load modules during boot but not really sure how or why.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike certain other operating systems such as Windows, which builds a list of the hardware with its corresponding drivers that it will follow every boot, many Linux distributions will include kernel modules to support most hardware configurations to provide the ease of use that you seem to like.

Doing that obviously makes the boot process longer as the hardware is probed by all the included drivers (kernel modules) instead of just the ones you need.  Thanks to the Linux kernel's design, that whole process isn't normally (much) slower than running a pre-configured system, but a customized Linux installation could boot up faster.

Comment: So on boot the system will basically detect what devices are physically there and then load the drivers it needs, if of course it has the drivers avaliable?

Comment: It's actually done the other way around.  The drivers are loaded and if they don't detect anything they get dismissed.

Comment: Ah a very simple answer to what I presume is quite complicated under the hood.

Thanks!

Comment: Simple, and wrong.  This answer is spoiled by its first sentence, which is quite erroneous on several points.  For starters, "unlike" should be "like".  The operation of Linux has aped the operation of the Plug And Play subsystem in Windows for some years.  And of course, Windows PAP uses bus enumeration, from the root bus down.